# Why is Google Compute Engine not allowing me to create image?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, wowza

I'm trying to implement wowza streaming engine with google cloud using [this tutorial](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?560-How-to-set-up-Wowza-for-Google-Compute-Engine).

The problem I am having is that when i try to add the Wowza Streaming Engine image via the developer console it fails saying " Required 'read' permission for 'rawDisk.source' ". I have also tried adding the image via the command-line tool with no success.

From my research on this error, all I have been able to surmise is that maybe this particular image is no no longer publicly shared, but this seem highly unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried exactly what you said, followed the same tutorial and got the same error. While the tutorial is somewhat out-dated (as certain commands are no longer the same and so on), the image they provide should still be fine. I wasn't able to create my image via the Web UI but it **WORKED** via CLI.

Here's what you can do as a workaround:

```
gcloud compute images create [IMAGE_NAME] --project=[YOUR_PROJECT] --source-uri http://storage.googleapis.com/wowzamediasystems/wse/WowzaStreamingEngine-4.1.0.v2.image.tar.gz
```

As long as you're properly authenticated (for example `gcloud auth login`) the above command should work. I tested, and was **also able to create** my instance using the image it creates. SSHed to it without a problem.